# Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop crashes immediately when started

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop crashes immediately when started. Can someone please help with the issue?

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: WDExpress.exe
  Application Version: 12.0.30110.0
  Application Timestamp: 52cfa049
  Fault Module Name: clr.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.0.30319.34011
  Fault Module Timestamp: 52968a96
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0002122c
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 782b
  Additional Information 2: 782be157f2d91021756bc06173db3dc9
  Additional Information 3: 46e5
  Additional Information 4: 46e5747e5031a1cc13ede01b86f04375

Comment: Odds are 101 to 1 that you have a bad install. Try reinstalling Visual Studio and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I tried reinstalling everything about 3 times after removing completely, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have found the problem. The framework version 4.5.1 is the problem. I installed the VS Express version and then removed the Framework 4.5 which seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its either you didn't install it cleanly else you are trying to install VS 2013 which 64 bit into your 32 bit operating system. The only solution which I think can help you is try compatibility option in the properties.. try  running it at windows 7 service pack 1. try hit n trial method..

Comment: I am on Windows 8.1. The install was failing and I repaired it which was successful. Also, I am on 64 bit OS.

Comment: Not yet. I tried every option available online, but am not able to fix the issue